# tomcat and eclipse: starting server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

in my system i am using eclipse and tomcat server. I hav 3 different versions of tomcat servers.

But i am trying to run only one server at a time. But by default Already one server is running on port number 8080. When i am trying to start the tomcat server in 8081 port, the tomcat server is not getting start.
I have configured my tomcat home, and server.xml in eclipse properly. But I don't know what I am missing. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have your port numbers defined and each tomcat instance is fighting to grab the port range first before the others.

Check your config file to make sure the port numbers are specified for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

see how to change port in y=tomcat , may be you forgot to change some where
http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

you can  stop another tomcat service before you start your tomcat gets started , end process `tomcatX`(X is version) from task-manager

Comment: eclipse is by default running the tomcat on 8081 port. I have configured the tomcat to my tomcat of version 6.0 with the port number 8080 in eclipse. But still when i am trying to run tomcat from eclipse it is running on 8081 port only...